# PySpark Schema should be specified in DDL format as a string literal or output of the schema_of_json function instead of schemaofjson(`col1`);

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to infer a schema from a json like string with schema_of_json function and then use the schema to format that string value as a struct using from_json function. My code is

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sqlf
dfTemp = readFromEventHubs()
df= dfTemp.withColumn("col1", sqlf.get_json_object(col("jsonString"), '$.*'))
col1Val= df.col1
jsonSchema = sqlf.schema_of_json(col1Val)
df.select(sqlf.from_json(df.col1, jsonSchema).alias("jsonCol"))
```

but I have the following exception

```
AnalysisException: 'Schema should be specified in DDL format as a string literal or output of the schema_of_json function instead of schemaofjson(`col1Val`);'
```

Just a precision,  I'm using spark streaming.

What's wrong with my code, Thank you

Comment: Just a precision. I'm using spark 2.4 then ```schema_of_json``` can take a ```pyspark.sql.Column```  as an input argument. The column col1 is a column of JSON format string and actually I don't know the schema before reading, I'm using spark streaming

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: We involve Databricks but there is no solution for now when using the structured streaming.

Comment: But there are some workaround using using azure eventhubs libraries or spark streaming

Answer (score 1):

`schema_of_json` expects a string representing a valid JSON object. You’re passing it a `pyspark.sql.Column`, likely because you’re hoping it will infer the schema of every single row. That won’t happen though.

`from_json` expects as its first positional argument a Column, that contains JSON strings and as its second argument `pyspark.sql.types.StructType` or `pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType` or even (since 2.3) a  DDL-formatted string or a JSON format string (which is a specification).

That means you can’t infer per row a different schema.

If you know the schema before reading (chances are that you do know it), then pass it in (”schema-on-read”) when you call `from_json`. If you’re not fixed on Databricks Delta, you could use a different DataFrameReader: `spark.read.json`, leaving its keyword argument `schema` unspecified so that it will infer the schema.

Comment: Note that you actually can pass a Column to `schema_of_json`. It’s just that this then has to be a Column of the string literal that represents the JSON. Put differently, `sqlf.schema_of_json(lit("{'a': 1}"))` is still valid.

Comment: I'm using spark 2.4 then schema_of_json can take a Column as input as you  mentioned. The column col1 is a column of JSON format string. Actually I don't know the schema before reading advance.

Comment: You’re still passing a Column to `from_json`’s 2nd positional argument (allowed, at least in the Scala API, but it likely won’t do what you intend). Can you not peek at the data and manually infer the schema?

Comment: yep I'm passing a Column of  ```schemaofjson()```  to ```from_json``` and that's correct. If I used 
```col1Val= sqlf.lit('''{"a": 0}''');
    jsonSchema = sqlf.schema_of_json(col1Val)
```
 instead of 
```col1Val = df.col1;
jsonSchema = sqlf.schema_of_json(col1Val)
``` 
I got a good result, And in both cases ```col1Val``` is  Column of ```schemaofjson()```
The only difference is for the first case it's ```Column<b'schemaofjson({"a": 0})'>``` but  ```Column<b'schemaofjson(col1)'>``` in the latter.

Comment: Hey @Bentech, could you perhaps edit your question by adding _what_ you want to do, rather than _how_ you’re trying to do it? I’ll either delete my answer or update it, because it looks like you’re trying to use some functions that won’t work the way you intend them to, as I tried explaining.

Comment: What I want is "I'm trying to infer a schema from a json like string with schema_of_json function and then use the schema to format that string value as a struct using from_json function."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203631/discussion-between-oliver-w-and-bentech).

Comment: "likely because you’re hoping it will infer the schema of every single row" That's precisely what I'm trying to do.What is the workaround @OliverW.?

Comment: @VictorKironde the real question is: why do you want to infer the schema on a per row basis? If the rows contain a JSON string, where each string can have an entirely different schema, then you’re dealing with semistructured data. Perhaps explaining what the use case is can help to create a sensible answer.

Comment: The data I'm streaming is semistructured - has a predefined Schema but one of the columns is a json string. I want to convert the json string to an object in order to stream to ElasticSearch

Comment: The json string column can change arbitrarily

Comment: @VictorKironde could you perhaps ask this in a new question and add at least two examples that indicate the schema of the JSON is different? I'm sure you'll get some good replies that way.